# How to run `scalaz.FreeT` into non-stack-safe monad?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to wrap my head around the free monads (and transformers). I've been able to construct my own free monad using `scalaz.FreeT` and an interpreter that runs it into a seemingly arbitrary monad by first naively hoisting into target monad and then running the free monad, like this:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

type MyCoolMonad[A] = FreeT[SomeFunctor, Id, A]
type ResultMonad[A] = ??? // for example Id[A]
def id2monadNT[R[_]: Monad]: (id ~> R) = { 
  override def apply[A](fa: A) = fa.point[R]
} // for hoisting
val myInterpreter = new (SomeFunctor ~> ResultMonad) {
  override def apply[A](fa: SomeFuntor[A]) = {...} // the meat is here
}

def runCoolMonad[A](m: MyCoolMonad[A]) = 
  m.hoistN(id2monadNT[R]).runM(myInterpreter.apply)
```

So, the first and less important question is, **do I have to do the hoisting** in oder to run the free monad into other arbitrary monad? It seems somehow excessive...

And the main course: the `.runM` requires `ResultMonad` to provide a `BindRec` instance which proves that one can bind over `ResultMonad` in constant stack space. I would like to have an interpreter that runs my free monad using `scala.concurrent.Future` as a result - and that is not stack safe. Is there any way to do that? I know that I give up on a certain guarantee, but as the dev I can have the confidence that `Future.flatMap` stack won't be deep enough to cause any trouble (we're using plain `Futures` without free monads everywhere and it works fine)

I'm using Scalaz 7.2.1, which to my knowledge is the most recent.

Sidenote: I am aware of `scalaz.concurrent.Task` existence, and I would still like to know how to interpret free monad into `scala.concurrent.Future`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: If you only have `FreeT[SomeFunctor, Id, A]`, it is equivalent to `Free[SomeFunctor, A]`. Then given `SomeFunctor ~> Future`, you can interpret the `Free[SomeFunctor, A]` to `Future[A]`. I.e. no need for `FreeT` and hoisting. Also, `Free` allows you to interpret to any monad.

`FreeT` is a more recent addition to `scalaz`. While `Free` was first designed to interpret to any monad and the stack-safe versions of operations were only added later, `FreeT` from the beginning supports only stack-safe monads.

If you still want to use `FreeT` with `scala.concurrent.Future`, just provide a `BindRec` instance.

```
implicit def futureBindRec: BindRec[Future] = new BindRec[Future] {
  def tailrecM[A, B](f: A => Future[A \/ B])(a: A): Future[B] =
    f(a) flatMap {
      case -\/(a1) => tailrecM(f)(a1)
      case \/-(b) => Future(b)
    }
  def map...
  def bind...
}
```

This might even be stack safe, if `Future#flatMap(f)` never calls `f` eagerly (which maybe it does on a completed `Future`, but I'm not familiar enough with it to tell).

Comment: I'd rather build monad transformers than plain monads for the sake of composability. Good point on providing `BindRec[Future]` instance - I just blindly assumed it's not possible, I'll check whether that works. My initial problem is solved, but do you have any other insights on how to interpret `FreeT` in truly non-stack-safe monads?

Comment: The above implementation of `BindRec` can be adapted pretty much verbatim for any monad. It just has the potential to overflow the stack on some. So it is as good as it gets.

Comment: Another roundabout way would be to hoist `FreeT[S, M, A]` to `FreeT[S, Free[M, ?], A]`, interpret it into `Free[M, A]` (which is stack safe), and then interpret that into a non-stack-safe monad `M`.

Comment: Of course `FreeT` could be extended with methods that interpret into any monad. I'm not convinced though that it would be super-useful.